# Rails 3.1 rc4 and Jquery: beginner's question

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to jquery and i just upgraded to rails 3.1 rc4 and i'm now starting a new project.

So far i've figured i can just convert my jQuery code to coffeescript and place it in something.js.coffee, for example

BUT: where should i place pure jquery code?

I'm trying to get this simple example to work: http://api.jquery.com/hide/
I've tried putting the following code in application.js and home.js.coffee but nothing worked so far..

```
 $("p").hide();
    $("a").click(function ( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the places you've suggested (application.js or a specific coffeescript file) are valid - though it should be written in the coffee syntax if you're putting it in a coffeescript file.

You need to put that code within a `$(document).ready` function to get it to work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").hide();
  $("a").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I completely forgot about $(document).ready!!